# first show input and then obscure pin code field effect

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is the sample, So when the user enters pin code it should show the number entered first, and then hide it after few seconds or when the user enters the next character.

How can I have such effect, or which package can do this, I've tried pin_code_text_field package and it has no such property

[image]

Comment: Can you please post some code snippets?

Comment: @ShripadJadhav what code you mean? I don't know what to code for this case yet)

Comment: Not needed now. Please check answer.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know other packages or plugin for intended behavior but you can use [TextFields](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) and its [obscureText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/obscureText.html) and to show bullet [obscuringCharacter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/obscuringCharacter.html). For some mili seconds it will show the entered pin code and then it will convereted to bullet. But you need do UI custumization for intended UI